# Layout for menu

Tags: android, layout, menu, icons

I want my menu look like this:

[image]

I want the icon to always stay in center in each grid.  So it's looks good on different screen sizes.

Now my code looks like this, but it dont look good when screen gets bigger.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center" 
android:background="@drawable/water">

 <TableRow
     android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center" >

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/imageButton_city"
         android:layout_width="128dp"
         android:layout_height="128dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
         android:background="@null"
         android:contentDescription="@string/city_des"
         android:scaleType="fitCenter"
         android:src="@drawable/city_button" />

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/imageButton_states"
         android:layout_width="128dp"
         android:layout_height="128dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
         android:background="@null"
         android:contentDescription="@string/state_des"
         android:scaleType="fitCenter"
         android:src="@drawable/states_button" />

 </TableRow>

 <TableRow
     android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center" >

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/imageButton_currency"
         android:layout_width="128dp"
         android:layout_height="128dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
         android:background="@null"
         android:contentDescription="@string/converter_des"
         android:scaleType="fitCenter"
         android:src="@drawable/currency_button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_tip"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/tip_des"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/tip_button" />

 </TableRow>

 <TableRow
     android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal|center" >

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/imageButton_information"
         android:layout_width="128dp"
         android:layout_height="128dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
         android:background="@null"
         android:contentDescription="@string/information_des"
         android:scaleType="fitCenter"
         android:src="@drawable/information_button" />

 </TableRow>
```

Can someone please give me a lite tip how I can accomplish this?

EDIT:

With help from David I fixed it. This is how the code looks like this now:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton                
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            ...>
        </ImageButton>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton                
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            ...  >
        </ImageButton>
    </RelativeLayout>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            ...  >
        </ImageButton>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton                
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            ...   >
        </ImageButton>
    </RelativeLayout>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageButton
        ...  >
    </ImageButton>

</TableRow>
```

Comment: Check out my answer below. I added a couple of examples which should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not wrap your `ImageButton` in a `RelativeLayout` and give the `ImageButton` the attribute `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`? The child of the `TableRow` would be a `RelativeLayout`, who has an `ImageButton` child which would always be perfectly centered. Now, the view hierarchy would look something like this:

```
<TableRow
    ... >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        ... >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            ... >

        </ImageButton>
    </RelativeLayout>
</TableRow>
```

Also, for rows which have two buttons, you can wrap the `RelativeLayout` in a single `LinearLayout` and give each `RelativeLayout` a weight of 1, which will evenly distribute space, 50% to each view, or 33.3% if you have 3, 25% with 4, etc... An example would be this:

```
<TableRow
    ... >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        ... >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            ... >

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                ... >

            </ImageButton>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            ... >

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                ... >

            </ImageButton>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot. had to make some changes to make it work as I wanted. I didn't need the LinearLayout. I change my post to show how my new code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515174/android-how-to-center-view-within-column-of-tablelayout) you can use `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` the center the images.