# Center checkbox programmatically?

Tags: android

I'm got a stretched table and I want my checkbox to appear central also within the table row. On the textView I've called:

```
            myTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

And I've also tried setting it as a table parameter:

This is my XML that sets up the table:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3,4" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedheader" >
```

And this is the code I'm calling as I create each row:

```
    //set table margin
    TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams= new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    int leftMargin=0,rightMargin=0,bottomMargin=0;
    int topMargin=5;

    tableRowParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);
    tableRowParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    row.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);

    // add the TableRow to the TableLayout
    table.addView(row);
```

However the same command doesn't have the desired effect on the checkbox. Does any know what the difference is and what I need to do. The checkbox isn't within any other layout its just in the table row.

Comment: How does your xml look like?

Comment: you can see this (may be)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515174/android-how-to-center-view-within-column-of-tablelayout?rq=1

Comment: I've tried the solutions in that thread - no joy! Prakash I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you before start working with TableLayout to check these links:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html

Also there is bunch of examples how to work with `TableLayout` in API Demos from Android SDK.

Assuming your layout `android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3,4"` you will have at least 5 columns, but from the code snippet I can't assume how many views are added to `row`. You will need to specify `TableRow.LayoutParams` `android:layout_span` if there are less view elements then columns and you want to use that free space. So assuming that you have only one `CheckBox` in a row and only 5 columns you will need to do next:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
rowParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
rowParams.span = 5;
checkBox.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
```

Also I recommend you to use xml layouts instead of creating them from the code. If you can't stick with xml layouts then at least create them using xml editor, so you will have good start point for creating them from the code.